# Does anyone know a solution to this PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I ran into this PDE:

$$\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial t} = A\,x^{\gamma-1} \left(\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial x} + x \, \frac{\partial^2 y(x,t)}{\partial x^2}\right)$$

If it helps in any way, this is for a physical system, where $x,y,t$ and $A$ are positive real numbers and we just care about solutions in $x>0$.

For starters, a solution for $\gamma=1$ would already be enough:

$$\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial t} = A \left(\frac{\partial y(x,t)}{\partial x} + x \, \frac{\partial^2 y(x,t)}{\partial x^2}\right)$$

I got as far as to find the solution in Fourier space for a Dirac delta distribution as initial condition $y(x,0)= F \, \delta(x-\hat x)$, which is:

$$ y(k,t) = \frac{F}{2\pi}\,\exp\left(-\frac{\mathrm{i} \, \hat x \, k}{1-A\, \mathrm{i} \, k\, t}\right) \, \left(1-A\, \mathrm{i} \, k\, t\right).$$

But now I fail to get a nice closed-form expression for the inverse Fourier transform of that solution. Can anyone find that, or find another way to solve for $y(x,t)$?

Comment: @ John Smith:  what physical system is this for?

Comment: @RobertLewis: its diffusion in a cylindrical system with power-laws for density and diffusivity.

Comment: @ John Smith:  thanks for the info!

Comment: for $\gamma = 1$ it is the generator of a squared bessel process.  these were studied by fourier methods in the 50's by Feller, and are well know today as the CIR interest rate processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\partiald{{\rm y}\pars{x,t}}{t}
=
Ax^{\gamma}\,\partiald[2]{{\rm y}\pars{x,t}}{x}
+
Ax^{\gamma - 1}\,\partiald{{\rm y}\pars{x,t}}{x}}.$

With the scaling $x = \alpha\tilde{x}$ and $t = \beta\tilde{t}$, we have

> \begin{align}
> {1 \over \beta}\,\partiald{y}{\tilde{t}}
> &=A\alpha^{\gamma}\tilde{x}^{\gamma}\,{1 \over \alpha^{2}}\,
> \partiald[2]{y}{\tilde{x}}
> + A\alpha^{\gamma -1}\tilde{x}^{\gamma - 1}\,{1 \over \alpha}\,\partiald{y}{x}
> \\[3mm]
> \partiald{y}{\tilde{t}}
> &=A\pars{\beta\alpha^{\gamma - 2}}\tilde{x}^{\gamma}\,\partiald[2]{y}{\tilde{x}}
> + A\pars{\beta\alpha^{\gamma - 2}}\tilde{x}^{\gamma - 1}\,\partiald{y}{x}
> \end{align}
> such that the equation is invariant whenever $\beta\alpha^{\gamma - 2} = 1$:
> $$
> 1 = {t \over \tilde{t}}\,\pars{x \over \tilde{x}}^{\gamma - 2}\quad\imp\quad
> {x^{1 - \gamma/2} \over t^{1/2}} = {\tilde{x}^{1 - \gamma/2} \over t^{1/2}}
> $$
> Let $\ds{\xi \equiv {x^{1 - \gamma/2} \over t^{1/2}}}$ and
> ${\rm y}\pars{x,t} \equiv \fermi\pars{\xi}
>  = \fermi\pars{x^{1 - \gamma/2} \over t^{1/2}}$:
> \begin{align}
> \partiald{{\rm y}\pars{x,t}}{t}
> &=
> \fermi'\pars{\xi}\,\pars{-\,{1 \over 2}\,{x^{1 - \gamma/2} \over t^{3/2}}}
> \\[3mm]
> \partiald{{\rm y}\pars{x,t}}{x}
> &=
> \fermi'\pars{\xi}\,{\pars{1 - \gamma/2}x^{-\gamma/2} \over t^{1/2}}
> \\[3mm]
> \partiald[2]{{\rm y}\pars{x,t}}{x}
> &=
> \fermi''\pars{\xi}\,{\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}x^{-\gamma} \over t}
> -
> \fermi'\pars{\xi}\,{\gamma \over 2}\,
> {\pars{1 - \gamma/2}x^{-\gamma/2 - 1} \over t^{1/2}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
-\,{x^{1 - \gamma/2} \over 2t^{3/2}}\,\fermi'\pars{\xi}
&=
Ax^{\gamma}\bracks{%
{\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}x^{-\gamma} \over t}\,\fermi''\pars{\xi}
-
{\gamma\pars{1 - \gamma/2}x^{-\gamma/2 - 1} \over 2t^{1/2}}\,\fermi'\pars{\xi}}
\\[3mm]&\phantom{=}\mbox{}+
Ax^{\gamma -1}\bracks{%
{\pars{1 - \gamma/2}x^{-\gamma/2} \over t^{1/2}}\,\fermi'\pars{\xi}}
\end{align}
Multiplying both members by the factor $\ds{2t^{3/2}x^{\gamma/2 - 1}}$
\begin{align}
-\fermi'\pars{\xi}
&=\bracks{%
2A\pars{1 - {\gamma \over 2}}^{2}\,\overbrace{t^{1/2}x^{\gamma/2 - 1}}
^{\ds{\xi^{-1}}}\,\fermi''\pars{\xi}
-
A\gamma\pars{1 - {\gamma \over 2}}\,
\overbrace{tx^{\gamma - 2}}^{\ds{\xi^{-2}}}\fermi'\pars{\xi}}
+
2A\pars{1 - {\gamma \over 2}}\,\overbrace{tx^{\gamma - 2}}^{\ds{\xi^{-2}}}
\fermi'\pars{\xi}
\\[3mm]&=
{2A\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2} \over \xi}\,\fermi''\pars{\xi}
+
{2A\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2} \over \xi^{2}}\,\fermi'\pars{\xi}
\end{align}
$\fermi\pars{\xi}$ obeys the equation:
$$
\fermi''\pars{\xi}
+
\bracks{%
{1 \over \xi} + {\xi \over 2A\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}}}\fermi'\pars{\xi} = 0
$$
Now, we multiply both members by the integrating factor
$\ds{\braces{\xi\exp\pars{{\xi^{2} \over 4A\bracks{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}}}}}$. It leads to:
$$
\totald{}{\xi}\bracks{%
{\xi\exp\pars{\xi^{2} \over 4A\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}}\fermi'\pars{\xi}}} = 0
\quad\imp\quad
\fermi'\pars{\xi}
=
{B \over \xi}\,\exp\pars{-\xi^{2} \over 4A\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}}
$$
where $B$ is a $\it constant$.

> \begin{align}
> \fermi\pars{\xi}
> &=\fermi\pars{\xi_{0}}
> +
> B\int_{\xi_{0}}^{\xi}\exp\pars{-z^{2} \over 4A\pars{1 - \gamma/2}^{2}}
> \ {\dd z \over z}
> \end{align}

Comment: @ Felix Marin: You seem to have made a mistake when you insert the definitions into the PDE (first multi-line equation). Correcting for this, I get the following ODE for $f(\xi)$:$$ f''(\xi)+f'(\xi)\left(\frac{\xi}{2 A (1-\gamma/2)^2}+\frac{1}{\xi}\right)=0.$$This gives me a solution of $$y(x,t) = f(0) + B \mathrm{Ei}\left(-\frac{x^{2-\gamma}}{A\,t\,(2-\gamma)^2}\right).$$ However, I fail to see where the initial condition comes in. Suppose you have a dirac delta function at some point $x_0$ at $t_0=0$. How can you calculate the time evolution? Can you help me out here?

Comment: @JohnSmith I'll check later since now I'm busy. It happens frequently with long calculations. Usually, I make the calculations directly on the screen. I call this $\tt CalcuTEX$. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith You were right. I just rechecked every thing.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it solves the original question. But do you know how this can use a delta function as initial condition?